# npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-y" "--no-install-recommends" "--global" "mathjax-node-cli"

Tags: python, docker

Good morning,
I was trying to install the following repository: https://github.com/AntoineMeler/Paraglidable
I simply ran the following command:

```
docker build -t paraglidable Paraglidable/docker/.
```

I got the following error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 5.4.0-97-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-y" "--no-install-recommends" "--global" "mathjax-node-cli"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7)
npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm WARN deprecated mathjax-node-sre@3.0.3: This package has been archived. MathJax v3 provides equivalent functionality.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
```

I searched online for the following problem, I believe it is caused by a deprecated version of the mathjax module but I don't understand how I can correct the problem.

Docker is running on ubuntu server 20.04.

Could you be so kind as to help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be related to the npm version used while installing the package `mathjax-node-cli`.

Installing a newer version of node.js will solve the issue, since it will also upgrade the npm version.

I've edited the Dockerfile as follows, and now it seems to be working.

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3

ARG USERNAME=paraglidable
RUN useradd -m $USERNAME
ENV HOME /home/$USERNAME

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

## Added the line below for installing node.js version 12 instead of 8.
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -

## Also removed `npm` from here since it is already included in `nodejs` package
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends net-tools libopenjp2-7-dev libpng-dev libpng16-16 vim sass wget qt5-default pdf2svg apache2 php libapache2-mod-php nodejs ibgeos-3.6.2 libgeos-dev unzip

# grib
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libgrib-api-dev libgrib-api0
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libeccodes-dev libeccodes0

# tex2svg
RUN npm install -y --no-install-recommends --global mathjax-node-cli

# Add sudo support
RUN apt-get install -y sudo \
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME


USER $USERNAME

RUN sudo pip install glob3 tqdm colorama requests pandas matplotlib pillow numba pyproj jupyter
RUN sudo pip install pygrib
RUN sudo pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip
```